# Как оптимизировать код JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Недавно начал изучать JS, для практики решил написать небольшой калькулятор.
Все в нем более-менее работает, но интересует вопрос, как оптимизировать код, т.к. во всех функциях 90% повторябщейся информации.

Создавал отдельную функцию Init() и выносил туда всю инициализацию переменных, вызывая ее в коде остальных функций. Однако, выдавало ошибки, что переменные не определены.

Помогите оптимизировать данный код.

```
    function sum(){
    let num1 = document.querySelector('#n1').value;
    let num2 = document.querySelector('#n2').value;
    let result;

    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);

    result = num1 + num2;
    document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML += result + ' ';
}

function dif(){
    let num1 = document.querySelector('#n1').value;
    let num2 = document.querySelector('#n2').value;
    let result;

    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);

    result = num1 - num2;
    document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML += result;
}

function dvs() {
    let num1 = document.querySelector('#n1').value;
    let num2 = document.querySelector('#n2').value;
    let result;

    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);

   if (num1 <= 0 || num2 <=0){
       alert('Числа должны быть больше 0');
   }
   else {
       result = num1 / num2;
       document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += result + ' ';
   }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте хтмл и цсс плиз, чтобы Ваш код можно было воспроизвести полностью. )

Comment: Ну как минимум `num1, num2 и result` вынести из каждой функции и сделать глобальными

Comment: Как вариант, сделайте функцию, которая возьмет значения из формы, выполнит parseInt и вернет массив из двух значений, т.е. буквально `return [ num1, num2 ]`. В остальных функциях ее вызывать и работать с массивом arr[0] и arr[1]

Comment: А с каких это пор 0 нельзя делить на что-либо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сразу вынести поиск элементов по дереву DOM и потом использовать их в остальных частях программы. Поскольку значения будут меняться, то их сразу получать смысла нет и лучше делать это в процессе. В общем можно как-то так сделать.

```js
(_ => {
    let n1 = document.querySelector('#n1');
    let n2 = document.querySelector('#n2');
    let out = document.querySelector('#out');
    
    document.querySelector('#sum').onclick = () => {
        out.innerHTML += `${parseInt(n1.value) + parseInt(n2.value)} `;
    }

    document.querySelector('#dif').onclick = () => {
        out.innerHTML += `${parseInt(n1.value) - parseInt(n2.value)} `;
    }

    document.querySelector('#dvs').onclick = () => {
        let [v1, v2] = [parseInt(n1.value), parseInt(n2.value)];
        if (v1 <= 0 || v2 <=0)
            alert('Числа должны быть больше 0');
        else 
            out.innerHTML += `${v1 / v2} `;;
    }
    
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="n1" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="n2" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <label id="out" />
</div>
<br />
<button id="sum"> + </button>
<button id="dif"> - </button>
<button id="dvs"> / </button>
```

P.S. Обертку `(_ => { /* код */ })();` из кода можно удалить, она нужна только для того, чтобы не захломлять глобальное пространство и переменные `n1`, `n2`, `out` не были видны за пределами этой обертки.

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите, что в вашем случае означает знак доллара? 
$ - ранее встречал только в JQuery.

Comment: @KekJS это [форматирование строк](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting), которое появилось в ES6. Используя обратные косые кавычки `\`` и знак `$` внутри них, можно вставлять внутрь строки выражения JavaScript. К примеру выражение `"привет " + name + " ваш номер +8 " + tel` можно написать проще `\`привет ${name} ваш номер +8 ${tel}\``.